# Models for binary outcomes: creating a balanced Recall?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, cross-validation, binary-data, cross-entropy

I am running an experiment where the target variable is a binary category. I have tried various algorithms, from XGBoost through to multi-layer networks in Keras. In the case of my neural network, I use a variety on the *adam* learner, with *binary_crossentropy* as my loss.

Due to the nature of the problem, it is challenging to have similar Precision when compared to Recall. Accordingly, I am careful not to over fit and optimize using k-folds validation techniques.

However, I notice that my model is very prone to performing very well for one category at the expense of the other. The average of the recall could remain constant at 0.6, but the recall for binary **category 0** is significantly higher than binary **category 1** (e.g. 0.8 vs. 0.4). It would be much more preferable for performance in both categories to be 0.6 for this use-case.

While I firm up the model, I have ensured that the number of examples presented both during training and testing are balanced, so the model does not see more of any one category than the other.

Is there a better approach to forcing my model to find a balance across both categories, by perhaps using a different loss function for my neural network, or a different modelling approach altogether.

Comment: You did not state your goals.  If you want to estimate the probability of outcome, precision and recall are improper accuracy scoring rules.

Comment: It's as simple as in a binary situation, the default 'threshold' for decision is usually .5 probability for class membership. My issues is that I sometimes find a significant imbalance in the recall performance of the models, despite using a binary cross entropy. I was wondering whether this is a commonly incurred issue, and also how to resolve. As it is, I just adjust my threshold until I find an acceptable balance between precision and recall for each of the binary classes

Comment: You are confusing things.  The first order of business is to get a representative sample of observations and fit a probability model to the whole sample.  Show that the estimated probabilities are well calibrated.  Then make the predictions, and if you feel your utility function is consistent with using a trigger level of 0.5, make your judgments of predicted probabilities in that light.